# Simple theory behind getting the property name from a for-in loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, object, loops

First of all, I want to say that I'm huge on theory. I don't like abstraction. I want to know how things work before trying to use them. I have been searching everywhere for a simple theory behind getting the property name (not the value) for a for-in loop. I will demonstrate it in code so hopefully someone can potentially explain how it works exactly...

```
var obj = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }; // A basic object instantiated with 3 public properties.

for (var prop in obj) {
    console.log(prop); // logs "one", "two" and "three" ???
}
```

I figured it would evaluate prop variable as 1, 2 and 3 but it logs out the actual property name. I know obj[prop] is what evaluates to the actual value of those properties but this is like an inception to me. prop is a reference that stores another reference?

I'm trying to think about this in terms of how variable i in a for loop is kinda like the index of an array.

Also what is this and is it similar to what I'm asking?

```
var obj = { "one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3 };
```

How are the property names strings?... You can't say var "string" = "Hello, World!"; as thats illegal.

Comment: I don't have the background to explain it for JavaScript, but it sounds like your answer will be related to "Reflection".

Comment: You're huge on theory, but you don't like abstraction? Does..not..compute.....

Comment: I yi yi... My grammar is terrible. What I mean by that is I don't like stuff to be abstract. Like, I want to have it explained in fullest detail possible if you know what I mean.

Comment: @W3Geek: Sounds like you are huge on the _opposite_ of theory — practical implementation :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have to admit I don't fully understand the question, but I try to answer as best as I can nonetheless. An *object* is pretty much comparable a *hash* (-*table*). As you know, that consist out of an identifier and a value which is stored behind that identifier.

In ECMAscript, that identifier is the *key* within an *object*.

For an *Array*, there is only one interesting thing you want to receive when looping over it, since its "*keys*", are just indexed numbers (which in reality are also *Strings* here, but that just as a sidenote). But, since object *keys* can be anything, there is a conflict when looping them. Do you want to get the *key* or the *value* ?

Thats why there is the `for-in` loop. You're looping over the *keys* and with that key you might also be access the value behind.

---

However - you are not fully alone with the confusion. That is why *ECMAscript Next* will introduce the `for-of` loop for objects, which inverts this logic. Instead of *keys* you will directly loop over the values.

```
var obj = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 };

for(var value of obj) {
    console.log(value); // 1, 2, 3
}
```

Comment: Neither of them (for in and for of) are ideal, should just provide syntax to expose a key and value in a same loop :P Kinda like php: `for( value in obj)`, `for( key, value in obj)` or whatever

Comment: I agree - I like PHP's array loop syntax. About the only good thing about it.

Answer (score 3):

The names of object properties *are* strings, `obj.prop` is just syntactic sugar for `obj["prop"]` when `prop` is a valid identifier. You can't for instance say `obj.my property`, you have to write `obj["my property"]`

`for..in` enumerates the enumerable keys in an object and its prototype chain, assigning the current string key to the left side. So you can do this:

```
var a = [], i = 0;
for( a[i++] in obj );

//a is an array: ["one", "two", "three"]
```

As the loop progresses, the left side is evaluated to a reference (`i` increments as a side effect of this) and assigned the current key. So it looks like `a[0] = key`, `a[1] = key2` and so on.

If you want all the details, see the specification for:

- [for-in
  statement](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.4)
- [object initialiser
  syntax](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5)
- [accessing
  properties](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1)

Answer (score 1):

A JavaScript object is a dictionary, with the keys being arbitrary strings, not necessarily valid JavaScript identifiers. Hence there are things you can use as property names (namely, any valid string), but not as variable names.

For/in is defined to loop over the (enumerable) property *names* (i.e. the keys), which is also true for arrays, such that

```
for (var i in [10,20,30]) document.write (i);
```

will print "012", rather than "102030".

A property can be defined to be non-enumerable, in which case for/in will skip it. In ECMAScript 5, you can define non-enumerable properties yourself. Enumeration order is undefined. Note that for/in also considers the properties of the prototype (which is the reason for the fact that you will frequently see a `hasOwnProperty` condition immediately inside the loop).

Comment: That is cool. I never know you could do use a for-in loop with an array. One-up!

Comment: The downside is that you should never use a for-in loop with an array, it's an order of magnitude slower \[than a for loop\], breaks with extension methods and the iteration order is undefined

Comment: ECMAScript 5 should solve this: `[10,20,30].forEach (function (i) { document.write (i); })` prints "102030"` and is much nicer than a `for` loop -- for geeks and aesthetes, at least.

Answer (score 1):

> prop is a reference that stores another reference?

No, `prop` is the key of the element you've reached in your iteration. A string.

*That's it.* Nothing more complicated than that.

> You can't say var "string" = "Hello, World!"; as thats illegal

It's also a completely different language feature...

Arguably, objects were provided *at least in part* to workaround the very restriction you've identified.